# How should I save set of information about a person?

Tags: android

I am accessing information about a person from a database, and I want to be able to access all of the details about a person, including things such as their name, address, date of birth etc.I am trying to work out what the best way to this would be.

Should I simply create a container class where I put all of the information about a person into it? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you mean display by "access all of the details", just write a GUI to access the information from the database and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Object class with fields related to person detail, something like this :

```
    public class Frame_Data {

        private int mUSER_ID;

        private int mPKG_ID;

        private int mFRAME_ID;

        private String mFRAME_NAME;

        private String mPREVIEW_IMG_PATH;

        private String mFULL_IMG_PATH;

        public void set_PKG_ID(int PKG_ID) {
            this.mPKG_ID = PKG_ID;
        }

        public Integer get_PKG_ID() {
            return mPKG_ID;
        }

        public void set_USER_ID(int USER_ID) {
            this.mUSER_ID = USER_ID;
        }

        public Integer get_USER_ID() {
            return mUSER_ID;
        }

        public void set_FRAME_ID(int FRAME_ID) {
            this.mFRAME_ID = FRAME_ID;
        }

        public int get_FRAME_ID() {
            return mFRAME_ID;
        }

        public void set_FRAME_NAME(String FRMAE_NAME) {
            this.mFRAME_NAME = FRMAE_NAME;
        }

        public String get_FRAME_NAME() {
            return mFRAME_NAME;
        }

        public void set_PREVIEW_IMG_PATH(String PRIVIEW_IMG_PATH) {
            this.mPREVIEW_IMG_PATH = PRIVIEW_IMG_PATH;
        }

        public String get_PREVIEW_IMG_PATH() {
            return mPREVIEW_IMG_PATH;
        }

        public void set_FULL_IMG_PATH(String FULL_IMG_PATH) {
            this.mFULL_IMG_PATH = FULL_IMG_PATH;
        }

        public String get_FULL_IMG_PATH() {
            return mFULL_IMG_PATH;
        }


}
```

And if you want you can also create an ArrayList of this object. Now whenever or wherever you want you can use this object to get values.

Comment: So basically just create a "Person" container class?

Comment: Yes. I think this would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what you want to do with the information. If you need to manipulate the data somehow, then creating a `Person` class would be wise - you're acting on a person and so it makes sense for them to be an object. If however you want to use the data in a transient way, e.g., you're just going to display it, then using the results of the database query directly in a `displayPerson` method makes more sense.

Comment: Basically, for the moment the program just takes as input the persons name, and looks up the information about that person, before displaying it on the screen. However, in the future, we would like to be able to make certain changes, and then save them back to the database. Based on what you and the answer above write, it would probably be easiest to make a container class from the start, and populate that with all the information accessed from the database.

Comment: You're taking the best approach here. By encapsulating your data early (because you've identified its future benefit as an object) you're saving yourself some inevitable refactoring down the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this many info `name, address, date of birth`

- To Store Permanently

  1. `SharedPreference` To store small data like Username and PWDs and IDs [Example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)
  2. `SQLite` if the amount of data is large like Records [Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
- To Store  Static

  1. User `Application` class and store them runtime [Example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state)

Comment: Unfortunately there is quite a bit more information. That was just to give you an idea of what I meant.